# Access to MySql with SSL from C/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, c, ssl

I've configured MySql to use SSL and it worked well in PHP. But when i'm trying to connect to the databases with a C/C++ program, it doesn't work.

### Variables :

```
host = "localhost"
psw = "pass"
db = "database"
```

### Without SSL :

```
usr = "userNOSSL"
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(conn, host, usr, psw, db, 0, NULL, 0);
```

This one worked well. i can easily retrieve data with :

```
query = "SELECT x FROM y"

mysql_query(conn, query);

result = mysql_store_result(conn);

num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
    for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

mysql_free_result(result);
```

### With SSL (CLIENT_SSL tag) :

```
usr = "userSSL"
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(conn, host, usr, psw, db, 0, NULL, CLIENT_SSL);
```

**The Error**

> Error : my "MYSQL *conn;" object is not getting parameters like "without ssl". 
>           so, it occurs an exception :

```
A first chance of exception at 0x0f18c274 in test_Class.exe : 0xC0000005: 
Acces violation when reading on location 0x00000048.
An unhandled exception at 0x0f18c274 in test_Class.exe : 0xC0000005: 
Acces violation when reading on location 0x00000048.
```

at this line :

```
num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
```

Same error if i do :

```
mysql_ssl_set(.SOMEOPTIONTHERE.)
mysql_real_connect(conn, host, usr, psw, db, 0, NULL, 0);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did `mysql_ssl_set()` return? was it a success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your local host isn't set up correctly to handle SSL. Try this: http://www.chriscalender.com/?tag=ssluserlocalhost